# API Manager 2.0 version and Identity server 5.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We have a stack of WSO2 servers where Identity server 5.1. works with API Manager as key manager. These servers work in a production environment.

Now a new version of API Manager (2.0) have appeard and I found out in documentation that WSO2IS 5.1 isn't compatible to work as key manager with new API manager.

My question is:

It would be better:

To wait for a new IS version (5.2) and then to upgrade together API Manager and IS

or

To upgrade API manager now and to switch  functions of key manager from UIS to new API Manager and later install new IS version.

I think the first way is better because of changes in UM and AM databases for new API Manager. Now AM and UM databases are common for 2 servers.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommending to wait until Identity Server 5.2.0 released, also you can get the latest Identity Server 5.2.0-SNAPSHOT release [here](http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/wso2/is/wso2is/5.2.0-SNAPSHOT/). We are hoping to release IS 5.2.0 by mid of September.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. We are going to implement WSO2 servers (IS, AM and others) as Identity Management Suite in our university. This project have just started and I'll try to use Identity Server 5.2 (snapshot) because mid of September is not so far. Other stack of WSO2 servers works as ESB suite and it will continue to work with IS 5.1 for some time.

Comment: You are welcome, it's glad to hear that you are using WSO2 products in your University. If you want to contribute back to WSO2, you can share your case study with us through bizdev@wso2.com. We are happy to hear it.